# Does my wife filing for divorce in the USA count as an Islamic divorce according to the Sunni school of thought?

Tags: talaq, non-muslim-countries

Me and my wife married in another country in the Islamic way, then married again in a USA court. Now she filed for divorce in a USA court and I also signed paper but court haven't given a decision yet. If the court say yes for divorce, will this divorce valid for Islamic way also?  Question for Sunni. My intention is not to leave her. Have to sign papers because of attorneys.

Comment: Which sunni school of thought? There are 4, at least.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to hold her against her will, while she has legitimate reasons, it would be reprehensible, You signing the divorce documents because of the attorney shows something fishy on your part. Marriage is a sacred contract, you just can't abuse your privileged position as a husband. Although in Islamic Sharia'a you have to divorce her in the Islamic way, yet she would be free to exercise her rights under the US law should she be granted a divorce and you will not be able to hold her back. Therefore, it is better to come to senses and either amicably, sincerely patch up with her (ref Q: 4:35) before the Court grants her a divorce or just let her be free by uttering the divorce in prescribed way.